# a.s discontinuous on an interval but continuous in Probability?

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, continuity

Can a Gaussian process be almost surely discontinuous on an interval T but at the same time be continuous in Probability everywhere on T?

Alternative question: can a sequence of discontinuity points converge to a point where the Gaussian process is continuous?

Thank you very much for your input!

Answer (score 1):

[Robert J. Adler's book](https://projecteuclid.org/ebooks/institute-of-mathematical-statistics-lecture-notes-monograph-series/An-introduction-to-continuity-extrema-and-related-topics-for-general/chapter/Miscellaneous-Frontmatter/lnms/1215467925)  *An introduction to continuity, extrema, and related topics for general Gaussian processes* has a lot of examples like this. In particular, on page 116 (exercise 6.1) he notes
that if $(X_t)$ is Gaussian, and stationary with $\mathbb{E}|X_u-X_0|^2\sim 1/|\log(u)|$ the sample paths are
discontinuous, though the process is continuous in probability.

Comment: Thank you! My process is not stationary and I was hoping to find some kind of criterion to check things like that.

Comment: @Lena Alder's book has loads of information on such processes, stationary and otherwise.